# Nginx configuration changes to use wordpress seo friendly URLs

Tags: wordpress, nginx, seo

I am trying to setup [SEO friendly URLs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) on wordpress website. In order to use it, I have made changes in Nginx configuration file as given on wordpress.org.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
}
```

But still it wont let me use SEO urls, it still redirecting all the pages and posts to index page.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like https://rtcamp.com/wordpress-nginx/tutorials/plugins/yoast-seo-sitemap/ has done this already and posted a configuration:

```
#Yoast sitemap
location ~ ([^/]*)sitemap(.*)\.x(m|s)l$ {
     rewrite ^/sitemap\.xml$ /sitemap_index.xml permanent;
     rewrite ^/([a-z]+)?-?sitemap\.xsl$ /index.php?xsl=$1 last;
     rewrite ^/sitemap_index\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
     rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;

     ## following lines are options. Needed for wordpress-seo addons
     rewrite ^/news_sitemap\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_news last;
     rewrite ^/locations\.kml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_local_kml last;
     rewrite ^/geo_sitemap\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_local last;
     rewrite ^/video-sitemap\.xsl$ /index.php?xsl=video last;

     access_log off;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change your code with this one and it should work fine.

```
location / {   
    try_files $uri     $uri/   /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

Don't forgot to reload the configuration.